# Do query in firebase-realtime-database

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

I have this structure in my firebase-realtime-database:

```
- child_n
  - child_n_1
   - $id_child_n_1
    - $subid_child_n_1
     - dates
      * 20180102: true
      * 20181102: true
      * 20181120: true
   - $id_child_n_2
    - $subid_child_n_2
     - dates
      * 20181103: true
      * 20181105: true
      * 20181204: true
```

I need to query under child dates and return those objects(id_child's) that contain dates from specific range.

I already tried something like:

```
query = db.reference(..).child(child_n/child_n_1).order_by_child(dates).start_at('specific_date').end_at('specific_date').get() not working, and return 0 objects!
```

I used ".indexOn":

```
"database_id":  {
      "child_n": {
        "child_n_1": {
          ".indexOn": ["dates_subid_child_n_1"]
        }
      }
    },

query = db.reference(..).child(child_n/child_n_1).order_by_child(dates).end_at('specific_date').get() working but return all objects.
```

Any idea how I can to perform this query???

Comment: I'm using firebase_admin

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there. When you use `order_by_child`, the nodes are ordered by the value of that child property. In this case you want to order by the `key` of each child node, which you do with `order_by_key`:

```
db.reference(..).child(child_n/child_n_1/dates).order_by_key().start_at('specific_date').end_at('specific_date').get()
```

Comment: how about child 'id_child_n_1' and 'subid_child_n_1', path that you mention will try to find 'dates' in child_n/child_n_1 node, where this doesn't exist, this are placed in: 'child_n/child_n_1/$id_child_n_1/$id_child_n_1/'

Comment: and this doesn't return any 'child_n_1' objects

Comment: Firebase Database queries work on a list of nodes. If you're trying to query a tree of nodes, that probably won't work. The probably here is because I find it hard to understand the actual meaning of your data structure. Consider updating your question with the actual concrete values, instead of abstract ids and numbers, to make it easier to understand the context.

Comment: So path that I can take in query is ‘child_n/child_n_1’ rest of path is specific id’s that I dont know from start, and I need to find some solution if this is possible.